# How to return back to previous script in expect

Tags: tcl, expect

I am trying to reboot a system using expect. Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout 20
set name [lindex $arg0]
set user [lindex $arg1]
set password [lindex $arg2]
spawn telnet $name
expect "login:"
send "$user\n"
expect "Password:"
send "$password\n"
expect "<system prompt>$"
send "<some command>\n"
expect "<system prompt>$"
send "./my_script\n" --> code is below
send "<back to the telnet system prompt and running a builtin command>"
expect "g>"
send "some built in command"
```

Here is the code for my_script (I am rebooting a system here after which the connection gets lost and the above script (main script) ends at line )

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set name [lindex <some ip>]
set user [lindex <name>]
set password [lindex <password>]
spawn telnet $name
expect "Login:"
send "$user\n"
expect "Password:"
send "$password\n"
expect "<system prompt>"
send "reboot\n"
expect "Are you sure you want to reboot (y/n)?"
send "y"
```

Here it lost connection and never returns to the main script and continue with the rest of the script.

NOTE: it's working if i put interact at the end of both the scripts but I don't want to put an interact as we don't want anything from user.

Comment: Your built-in commands execution is not happening which is mentioned in the main script ?

Answer (score 0):

Your inner script probably ought to do:

```
expect eof
close
exit
```

at the end. However, more generally you should add:

```
exp_internal 1
```

to your script (usually just before the `spawn`) when debugging it so that you can figure out what's going wrong. Otherwise you could be hitting unexpected problems and not know it.